# Make argument explicit?

Tags: c++, c++17, explicit

[`explicit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) can be used on eg. a constructor or conversion function to avoid implicitly calling that constructer/conversion - in short.

Im interested in if it is possible to make a single argument [explicit](/questions/tagged/explicit) somehow (short of roling a new type) ? perhaps using compiler extensions ?

Using a reference makes copy-construction impossible, so that is a solution, albeit not the one im looking for. It would be neat tool/interface specifier sometimes to be able to force `explicit` at a function level.

```
void f(std::string& s); //cannot copy convert into s

void f(const std::string& t);//calling with char* allowed
```

Specificly for strings, what type should be used to avoid construction from `char*` ?

Comment: You could define the same function name with a `char *` parameters as `void f(char *) = delete;`. Would that work?

Comment: in the specific case, that would probably work, yes

Answer (score 9):

You can't mark the parameter explicit, but what you can do is add an overload that has an rvalue reference parameter and delete it like

```
void f(const std::string& t);
void f(std::string&&) = delete;
```

What this will do is it will allow `f` to accept a `std::string`, but if an rvalue is created because of an implicit conversion then the rvalue reference overload will be selected instead and you'll get a compiler error about using a deleted function.

The reason this works is that an rvalue reference parameter beats a reference to const in overload resolution, so it will always be called when passing a temporary.  It's only after the function is selected that the compiler see that it's deleted so it issues an error.

Comment: Thats interesting, will try that

Comment: What if the purpose is to move from the string - but then only want std::string input ? not eg. char* - just a thought

Comment: Can you explain the process of how passing char* as a parameter to void f(const std::string& t); that it gets convert to an rvalue and ends up using void f(std::string&&) = delete; ?  I'm curious to understand this, thanks.

Comment: @darune If that is the case you can use `void f(char *) = delete;` like John has in their comment.  I suggested this because other things can be implicitly converted to a string so this stops all of those with a single overload.

Comment: Yeah, I see, I just wanted to hear your thoughts on that too.

Comment: @noobius The compiler sees that there is `void f(const std::string&)` and `void f(const std::string&&)` as the possible overloads.  It looks at `std::string` to see if it can be implicitly created with a `char*`.  It finds that it can so then it runs the two functions through overload resolution against that temporary it just created. It picks `void f(const std::string&&)` because it is a better match, and then it sees it is deleted so an erorr is raised.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @darune: "*What if the purpose is to move from the string - but then only want std::string input ? not eg. char* - just a thought*" Is that a thing worth wanting to do? I don't know why you would want to make your interface forbid an action that is 100% valid.

Comment: @NicolBolas the old interface took a char* and took ownership of that - which was pretty bad semanticly. Then just changing the interface to char*->std::string would leave a memory leak on the caller side. Other cool Ideas are very welcome.

Comment: This of course prevents `f(return_a_string())`, which seems undesirable.

Answer (score 8):

With C++20, you can do:

```
void f(std::same_as<std::string> auto const& s);
```

With C++17, this is equivalent to:

```
template <typename T,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, std::string>, int> = 0>
void f(T const& s);
```

That is, we have to deduce `T` to be exactly `std::string` (which string literals or other `char` pointers obviously are not).

---

Note that this rejects types like:

```
struct D : std::string { };
```

Which would not require a conversion either. If you want to allow those, that's changing the concept to `std::derived_from` or the `enable_if` to use `std::is_convertible_v<T*, std::string*>`.

Comment: I love how answers with "with C++20 you can..." appear more and more! Great answer. You could also explain the concepts syntax behind that